# resume_pos parameter not work in ftp_nb_get PHP for big integer

Tags: ftp, resume

I have a problem with resume_pos in ftp_nb_get PHP function that not support big integer like 6335272359, so not affect and resume_pos set to zero :(

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem is because of PHP is not supported big integer even on x64 Windows platform.